# Quoting strings passed to an output stream

Tags: c++

This class allows me to quote strings being sent to an output stream:

```
class Quote{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Quote& obj){
        obj.write(os);
      return os;
    }
    Quote() = delete;
    Quote(const string & text): text(text){}

    void write(ostream & os) const{
        os << default_quote_token << text << default_quote_token;
    }
private:
    const string & text;
};
```

Like this:

```
os << Quote(name);
```

It feels like a lot of work to avoid:

```
os << "\"" << name << "\"";
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Apart from minor formatting issues I see nothing wrong. You could extend to support other types (and/or multiple objects).

Answer (score 2):

In C++14, there's `std::quoted`. Some advantages it has over your approach:

- It works with both output and input streams
- You can specify the delimiter and escape character
- It's a stream manipulator, allowing it to be used seamlessly with operations while yours is a one-off class with zero interoperability
- It supports wide strings